# How to send Multiple Validation errors from WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a case there i want to send multiple validation errors from WCF service.I need to iterate a list and validate each object and need to create a error list.I need to send this consolidated error messages as anexcpetion to client.Can anyone suggest which is preferred option in this scenario with an example.

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of a `List<Error> errors = new List<Error>();`

Comment: In case of WCF is any different approach possible..if i send a aggregate excpetion,it is recieving it as single excpetion and i can't itereate inner exceptions..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to return an array of errors (exceptions if you want) in your WCF service.

```
[OperationContract]
ResponseWithErrors SomeMethod(SomeRequest rq);

public class ResponseWithErrors : IResponseWithErrors
{
    public Error[] Errors { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```